# Datatables: export button not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to do dynamically change filename and change other variable after click export button. But it seem the new release got problem inside button.html5.js. Can anyone help me with this thing. Here is the error image and the link of my code.

[image]

```
buttons:    [{
              extend: 'excel',
              text:   'Excel',
              action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        exportExtension = 'Excel';

                        $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action(e, dt, node, config);
                      }
               }]
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saf21/sbcuzoy8/7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. The `action` method needs to be executed in the scope of the Buttons instance so it can access method attached to `this`. In this case you need to use:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, node, config);
```

See also [this thread on the DataTables forums](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/110838/#Comment_110838) on the same topic with this answer and a working test case.

Allan